# Access Redshift tables under a schema

Tags: r, postgresql, amazon-redshift, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to access some tables on Redshift  with shinyR that are under a schema, I can connect to a table that are not under a schema using library(RPostgresSQL)  so I know this part is working:

```
pconn_r <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),  
                 host = "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                 port = "5439",
                 user = "rcd_admin",
                 password = "xxxxxxx",
                 dbname = "xxxx"
```

)

but i'm unable to access my table fr__synapps_drug__outpatient_index under the schema synapps    with   this command :

```
sql_command <- "Select cip13_code,cis_label,presentation_label,brand,period,hco_code,hco_label,hco_code_type,hco_city,bse,rem,unit from  synapps.fr__synapps_drug__outpatient_index"
outpatient <- dbSendQuery(pconn_r, sql_command)
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the fetch statement. output_data <- fetch(outpatient, n = -1)

Comment: *I'm then unable to access data*... is not too clear. Please post error you receive or undesired results.

Comment: Is `fr__synapps_drug__outpatient_index` a table or an index?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' the database is oip, the schema is synapps and the table under this schema is fr__synapps_drug__outpatient_index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
myRedshift <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(), 
                         dbname = 'oip',
                         host = 'xxxx',
                         port = 5439,
                         user = "xxxadmin", 
                         password = "xxx")

cis_has_bdpm <-data.frame( dbGetQuery(myRedshift, "select * from synapps.fr__synapps_drug__has_index"))
```

I change the way to connect to Redshift and it's working, but the loading of the data is very slow